# Can I avoid display of expanded macro in failed assert()?

Tags: c, macros, assert

I wrote a helper macro:

```c
#define IMPLIES(a,b) (!(a) || (b))
```

Using that macro inside an `assert(...)`, the expanded macro text is output when `assert()` fails.
Example:

```c
(!(d_pos > s_pos) || (d_pos >= s_pos + count))
```

Is there a way to get the unexpanded condition when `assert()` fails without changing the definition of `assert()`, maybe by adding another wrapper macro?

Comment: I don't think so: The preprocessor is just a text replacement tool unaware of anything related to C (you could use it to process other files, too, like xml, csv, ...), and when the C compiler runs, text processing has already been completed entirely. You might replace with an inline function, though, that one is unaffected by the pre-processor. On the other hand you lose type unawareness that way, too, so not the Holy Grail either...

Comment: The output depends on compiler lib. gcc/glibc gives "Assertion 'IMPLIES(foo,bar)' failed." Do you want it to print `IMPLIES(a,b) (!(a) || (b)) failed` or...?

Comment: @Lundin Sorry, I don't understand what you are trying to say. I'm using gcc/glibc and the macro is expanded on failure.

Comment: What do you want the output to be?